# Query parsing only author ids

Tags: query, author, array, id

I need array only all author ids from the loop, each one only once if possible and out of all posts in the loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please share some code in order to understand better your situation and what you want. Also if possible please provide an example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205671/wordpress-query-parsing-only-author-ids

Comment: Please don't cross post on two network sites. And if you're doing it with a non network site (like wp.org forums) then please leave a link on both ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have an array of post objects in `$my_posts`...

```
$authids = array_unique(wp_list_pluck($my_posts,'post_author'));
```

What you will get are the post authors for the *current page of posts*, not the post authors for all of the posts. If you want the authors for all of the posts you will have run another query.

To run a new query based on the main query in `$wp_query`...

```
$this_query = array_unique($wp_query->query_vars);
$this_query['posts_per_page'] = -1;
$new_query = new WP_Query($this_query);

$authids = array_filter(wp_list_pluck($new_query->posts,'post_author'));
var_dump($authids); // debug
```

***I caution you against this.*** You could be querying hundreds or thousands of posts. That could be very inefficient or even cause server failures, depending on the server and the load. I am almost certain that there is a better way to do this if you think it through and alter your architecture.

## Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: but i need all of them its important, can you give me the code for the second query and array please?

Comment: that works perfectly thanks. i think my server can handle it, it has the best components. and i cant imagine anything better to filter the posts (in my case products for price comparsion) besides multiserver, what would be your suggestion? im gona use caching. would an normal php query need much less performance to get and sort the data than the wp query?

Comment: oh and one more thing, i need to show each author id only one time, it worked with this code: if(have_posts()){
   $author_arr = array();
   while(have_posts()){
        the_post();
        global $post;
        if(!in_array($post->post_author,$author_arr)){
           $author_arr[] = $post->post_author;
        }
    }
}              but it works only on current page, not all posts

Comment: Sorry. Use array_unique instead of array_filter

Comment: If this solved the problem, please mark it as accepted. Also,  straight MySQL query would probably be a bit more efficient but I don't know how much and it would definitely be harder to write though you could alter `$wp_query->request` to get the SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Normally there's the [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) to fetch users (/authors). But as I read that you want to have all authors from the *current page loop*-posts, it might be easier to hook into the loop it self and collect it.

```
<?php
namespace WPSE109876;

/** Plugin Name: WPSE (#109876) Collect Author IDs */
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;

\add_action( 'loop_start', array( __NAMESPACE__.'\LoopCollector', 'init' ) )
class LoopCollector
{
    public static $instance = null;

    public $stack = array();

    public function init()
    {
        is_null( self::$instance ) AND self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        \add_action( 'the_post', array( $this, 'toStack' ) );
        \add_action( 'shutdown', array( $this, 'printStack' ) );
    }

    public function toStack( $post )
    {
        $aid = absint( $post->post_author );
        ! in_array( $aid, $this->stack )
            $this->stack[] = $aid;
    }

    public function printStack()
    {
        printf( '<hr />Author IDs<pre>%s</pre>', join( "</br>", $this->stack ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: no i dont want the author ids only from current page but from all, the code from s_ha_dum is almost what i need, the only thing is he fetch every author id even if its multiple. so what i need is getting all author ids but when the author id is for example "2" on one or more posts, then the "2" should appear only one time in array

Comment: Ehm... "no"? Take a look at the exact first line of the answer.